# How to watch specific function calls and its arguments using Google Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know if it is possible to watch specific function calls and its arguments using Google Chrome developer tools.

For example using:

```
var myFunc= function(a,b){
};
```

I need to log the values passed in (`a,b`) every time `myFunc` is called in my application.

Comment: I would need this functionality in the console log itself, as I cannot add console.log in the code it self

Comment: As the library is on a CDN.

Answer (score 7):

I found answer to my question, basically I can use `monitor(function)` [resource here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#monitorfunction)

> monitor(function)
>
> When the function specified is called, a message is logged to the
> console that indicates the function name along with the arguments that
> are passed to the function when it was called.

Comment: Interesting related article https://raygun.io/blog/2015/06/useful-javascript-debugging-tips-you-didnt-know/